# How to prove this equality about series with exponential function?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need to prove this 
$$\frac{1}{N+1}\left| \sum \limits_{k=0}^N e^{2\pi i m k x}\right|^2 =\sum
\limits_{n=-N}^{N}\left( 1-\frac{|n|}{N+1}\right)e^{2\pi i m n x}$$

Comment: Have a look at Wikipedia, section **Fejér Kernel**.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Using obvious notation,
$$
\left|\sum_k a_k\right|^2=\left(\sum_k a_k\right)\overline{\left(\sum_j a_j\right)}=(\sum_k a_k)(\sum_j\overline{a_j})=\sum_k\sum_j a_k\overline{a_j}.
$$
The sums over $k$ and $j$ each run from $0$ to $N$, so that $k-j$ takes integer values from $-N$ to $N$. Group by $k-j$:
$$
\sum_k\sum_j a_k\overline{a_j}=\sum_{n=-N}^N\sum_{k-j=n}a_k\overline{a_j},
$$
where the inner sum $\sum_{k-j=n}$ means "sum over all $k$, $j$ pairs such that $k-j=n$". How many $k,j$ pairs have this property, and what is the value of $a_k\overline{a_j}$ for each of these pairs?